# Are mysql users from different origins different users?

Tags: mysql

Is Michael@192.168.1.10 and Michael@localhost a completely different user?  Could they have different passwords?  If so, what would happen if one was allowed to connect from any host?

```
mysql> SELECT Host,User FROM mysql.user;
+--------------+------------+
| Host         | User       |
+--------------+------------+
| 127.0.0.1    | root       |
| 192.168.1.10 | Michael    |
| ::1          | root       |
| localhost    | Michael    |
| localhost    | git        |
| localhost    | root       |
+--------------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

PS.  What I am ultimately trying to do is create a user which could connect from 192.168.1.* where * is a wildcard.  Not my question, but would appreciate a comment.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Access Control, Stage 1: Connection Verification](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/connection-access.html):

> The server accepts the connection only if the `Host` and `User` columns in some `user` table row match the client host name and user name and the client supplies the password specified in that row.
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> Your identity is based on two pieces of information:
>
> - The client host from which you connect
> - Your MySQL user name
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> It is possible for the client host name and user name of an incoming connection to match more than one row in the `user` table.
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> When multiple matches are possible, the server must determine which of them to use. It resolves this issue as follows:
>
> - Whenever the server reads the user table into memory, it sorts the rows.
> - When a client attempts to connect, the server looks through the rows in sorted order.
> - The server uses the first row that matches the client host name and user name.
>
> The server uses sorting rules that order rows with the most-specific `Host` values first. Literal host names and IP addresses are the most specific. (The specificity of a literal IP address is not affected by whether it has a netmask, so `192.168.1.13` and `192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0` are considered equally specific.) The pattern `'%'` means “any host” and is least specific. The empty string `''` also means “any host” but sorts after `'%'`. Rows with the same `Host` value are ordered with the most-specific `User` values first (a blank `User` value means “any user” and is least specific). For rows with equally-specific `Host` and `User` values, the order is indeterminate.

Therefore:

1. > Is Michael@192.168.1.10 and Michael@localhost a completely different user?

   Yes.
2. > Could they have different passwords?

   Yes.
3. > If so, what would happen if one was allowed to connect from any host?

   MySQL would first try to match against the more specific host specification, and only if that fails will it try to match against the wildcard host.